# Lambda upload files with cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I am deploying a cdk app that contains a lambda. I need to upload a file query.sql to be executed when the lambda is called.

Is there a way to specify files that needs to be uploaded when deploying the lambda.

```
const Lambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'My_Function', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
      handler: 'lambda.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../handler')),
      architecture: lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
      layers: [myLambda_layer]
}
```

Comment: Can you help us by sharing out your CDK code for the function provisioning?

Comment: Where does your code expect to find this SQL file?  Why is it not part of the Python package that you deploy to Lambda?

Comment: `lambda.Code.fromAsset()` bundles the entire folder you give it. Whatever files are there, including your `.sql` file, will be uploaded to Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them on the same directory where the `lambda.py` file is located at. You can then just read the text out of the SQL file using python's `open` function:

```py
fd = open('./my-personal-script.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

print(sqlFile)
```